# k-ordered array problem

Tags: data-structures, arrays

> An array $A[1...n]$ is said to be k-ordered if
>
> $$A[i - k] \leq A[i] \leq A[i + k]$$
>
> for all $i$ such that $k < i \leq n - k$.
>
> For example, the array $A = [1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 7, 5, 8]$ is 2 ordered.
>
> Q1. In a 2-ordered array of 2n elements, what is the maximum number of positions that an element can be from it's position if the array were 1-ordered?

```
a) 2n-1                b) 2
c) n/2                 d) 1                 e) n
```

> Q2. In an array of 2n elements, which is both 2-ordered and 3-ordered, what is the maximum number of positions that an element can be from it's position if the array were 1-ordered?

```
a) 2n-1                b) 2
c) n/2                 d) 1                 e) n
```

I can understand how the example array is two ordered, but I am having trouble understanding what the questions 1 and 2 are trying to say.

Can someone please explain to me the meaning of the questions in simple terms?

Thanks!

P.S. First time questioner here. Sorry if I missed anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take your example
$$ A = [1,4,2,6,3,7,5,8]. $$
An array is 1-ordered if it is ordered, and the 1-ordered array corresponding to $A$ is $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$. Let's write both arrays together:
$$
1,4,2,6,3,7,5,8 \\
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
$$
You can see that matching digits are at distance at most 2.

An array is 2-ordered if its even elements are 1-ordered and its odd elements are 1-ordered. This could be helpful in question 1. A similar property is true for 3-ordered arrays. How do these two properties combine? I suggest you try writing out a few 2- and 3-ordered arrays to see what the possibilities are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, if I am correct, the Q1's answer is `n/2` ??

Comment: @GaurangTandon I don't know. Not that you understand the question, you should be more confident in the answer. Try to convince yourself that your answer is correct.

Comment: I think I got it: Q1 = `2`, and Q2 = `1`, and the array both 3-ordered and 2-ordered is `[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8]`. I think now that this is indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

2.) Suppose A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] index from 1-10.
 k=3  from condition 3 < i <=10-3 for i=4,5,6,7

Applying condition:   A[i-k]<=A[i]<=A[i+k] 
 i= 4   A[1]<=A[4]<=A[7],    i=5 A[2]<=A[5]<=A[8],
 i= 6   A[3]<=A[6]<=A[9],    i=7 A[4]<=A[7]<=A[10]

3-ordered A=[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9,10]

k=2   from condition 2 < i <=10-2 for i=3,4,5,6,7,8

Applying condition:   A[i-k]<=A[i]<=A[i+k] 
 i= 3   A[1]<=A[3]<=A[5],    i=4 A[2]<=A[4]<=A[6],
 i= 5   A[3]<=A[5]<=A[7],    i=6 A[4]<=A[6]<=A[8],
 i= 7   A[5]<=A[7]<=A[9],    i=8 A[6]<=A[8]<=A[10]

2-ordered A=[1,4,2,5,3,6,8,7,9,10] similarly
1-ordered A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

so maximum position of the element is N/2 (see from 2-ordered A[8]=7 and from 3-ordered A[3]=7  so position = 8-3=5 but total number of element N=10 hence 10/2=5)

Now lets A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] index from 1-8.
k=3  from condition 3 < i <=8-3 for i=4,5

Applying condition:   A[i-k]<=A[i]<=A[i+k] 
 i= 4   A[1]<=A[4]<=A[7],    i=5 A[2]<=A[5]<=A[8],

3-ordered A=[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6]

k=2   from condition 2

Applying condition:   A[i-k]<=A[i]<=A[i+k] 
 i= 3   A[1]<=A[3]<=A[5],    i=4 A[2]<=A[4]<=A[6],
 i= 5   A[3]<=A[5]<=A[7],    i=6 A[4]<=A[6]<=A[8]

2-ordered A=[1,4,2,5,3,6,7,8] similarly
1-ordered A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

so maximum position of the element is N/2 (see from 2-ordered A[7]=7 and from 3-ordered A[3]=7  so position = 7-3=4 but total number of element N=8 hence 8/2=4)

Hence (C) N/2

1.) 
similarly , A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] index 1-10
2-ordered A=[1,4,2,5,3,6,8,7,9,10] 
1-ordered A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

so maximum position of the element is 2 (2-ordered A[2]=4, 1-ordered A[4]=4 hence position = 4-2=2 or 2-ordered A[5]=3, 1-ordered A[3]=3 hence position = 5-3=2)

Lets A= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
2-ordered A=[1,4,2,5,3,6,7,8]
1-ordered A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

so maximum position of the element is 2 (2-ordered A[2]=4, 1-ordered A[4]=4 hence position = 4-2=2 or 2-ordered A[5]=3, 1-ordered A[3]=3 hence position = 5-3=2)

Hence (b) 2

Comment: I recommend that you use Latex, and proof-read your answer before writing) - as it stands this is a wall of text that is quite imposing.