# What is an ordered array?

Tags: arrays

I am not able to find a clear explanation about Ordered Arrays. All I know is

> The array is 1-ordered it is in the usual order. (For the
>   1st must be less than the 2nd which in turn must be less than the 3rd
>   which ... which must be less than the $n$th.)

But what is 2-ordered, 3-ordered... so on array?

Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the definition from Gaurang Tandon's [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/25839/k-ordered-array-problem):

> An array $A[1...n]$ is said to be k-ordered if
> $$A[i - k] \leq A[i] \leq A[i + k]$$
> for all $i$ such that $k < i \leq n - k$.
>
> For example, the array $A = [1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 7, 5, 8]$ is 2 ordered.

I must also say that I've never seen a similar definition before (and I find it to be quite un-useful, but maybe it is important somewhere).

Another definition I have seen, extends the ordering to $k$-dimensional objects. For instance, with two dimensions:

> Given vectors $v=(v_1,v_2)$ and $u=(u_1,u_2)$,  we say that $v>u$ in a 2-ordering if
> $$v_1 > u_1$$
> or if
> $$ v_1=u_1 \text{ and } v_2>u_2$$

Then, an array of vectors $v[1...n]$ is $2$-ordered if for every $i$, $v[i]<v[i+1]$ via the above 2-ordering.